# Javascript date format from ADO recordset

Tags: javascript, ado, recordset, date-formatting

I retrieve a list of date from a DB using JS and ADO and I show it in a table with the following code:

```
var detDate = new Date() ;
      if(!rsDetail.bof) {
        rsDetail.MoveFirst()
        while(!rsDetail.eof) {
            detDate  = rsDetail.fields(2).value; 
            rsDetail.MoveNext()
        }
...  TableHtml += '<td>' + detDate + '</td>' ...
```

The output looks like that: Sat Oct 15 00:00:00 EDT 2011 
I want it to look like that: 2011-10-15 
I have been looking around at the JS date object and I tried to do `formatDate(detDate,'y-mm-dd')` but it doesn't work...

Comment: 1. the proper formatting string is `'yyyy-mm-dd'`
2. You can use the properties for that like this: `var dateStr = detDate.Year + '-' + detDate.Month...` etc (Sorry if the exact syntax is incorrect, im not experienced at JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your date object like that :

```
function formatDate(dt) {
    var pad = function(str, c, width) {
        while (str.length < width)
            str = c + str;

        return str;
    }

    var dateString = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + pad((dt.getMonth() + 1).toString(), '0', 2) + "-" +pad( dt.getDate().toString(), '0', 2);

    return dateString;       
}

tableHTML += "<td>" + formatDate(debDate) + "</td>";
```

Comment: you mean i will define the `var dateString` everytime it passes through the loop?

Comment: No you can put this code in a function and call it only when you build you table html